# Read rows from middle pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can I read rows from in-between in pandas df, like I have dataframe with 10 Million records and I want to read the records between 2 Million to 3 Million records. I know I can use skiprows but that won't solve my problem.

Solution:

```
start_point = 2000000, number_of_records_to_be_loaded = 1000000 #2M-1M
pd.read_csv(file,skiprows=start_point,nrows=number_of_records)
```

Comment: did you try df[2000000:3000001]?

Comment: I think @Chris_007 doesn't want to have to load the entire DataFrame first

Comment: Thanks @DerekO, saw your answer, I didn't see any csv mention but in this light question makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a callable function to skiprows so that `pd.read_csv` knows where to start and stop (this can be useful if you want a more complicated row selecting operation). For your question, this works:

```
pd.read_csv(filepath, skiprows=lambda x: x not in range(2000000,3000000))
```

Edit: as you suggested, the following also works:

```
pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=2000000, nrows=1000000)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, if I do:
```pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = 2000000, nrows = 1000000)```
then will this give me different output?

Comment: Your answer is not skipping any row if I'm not mistaking. It's returning all the records instead. Can you please check on small csv file if you have any.

Comment: Sure, let me check. Perhaps I misunderstood the pandas documentation

Comment: can you also check what I suggested is correct or not?

Comment: Oh my bad. `skiprows=lambda x: x in range(2000000,3000000)` will SKIP the rows between 2 and 3 million, so it should be `skiprows=lambda x: x not in range(2000000,3000000)`